# Refactor to avoid using for...next more than once

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, refactoring

I have this:

```
For k = 1 to 100
    Statement 1
Next

For j = 1 to 100
    Statement 2
Next

For l = 1 to 100
    Statement 3
Next
```

I would like to put all three Statements inside one single For...Next

```
For k = 1 to 100
    Statement 1
    Statement 2
    Statement 3
Next
```

however I can't, because the loops need to be ran sequentially for each statement (Statement 1 needs to be ran for all the values from 1 to 100 first, then the same but for Statement 2, etc...). Is there a way to simplify this? I am sure there must be. Thanks!

Comment: I reject the premise of this question. Your first code snippet is the right way to do it. You do not want to compress it. Saving 2 tiny lines of code is no good reason for making things more complicated and less readable. Heed the advice given to you by experienced programmers, here and in the answer you accepted. (And, by the way, you can use the same counter `k` for all three loops.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For n=1 to 3
For k = 1 to 100
    If n=1 Then Statement 1
    If n=2 Then Statement 2
    If n=3 Then Statement 3
Next
Next
```

But really your first example is tidier and putting all the statements inside a single loop does not simply things at all...

Answer (score 1):

I reject the main thrust of this question.

Your first code snippet is a much better way to do it than shoehorning everything into one `For...Next` loop force-fed with weird conditionals. That would make things more complicated and less readable, and saving a couple of miserable lines of code is no good excuse to do this.

To answer your question more explicitly: Is there a way to simplify this?

On one level, hardly, because the code you show is so simple.

But in the general case, any complexity should be broken down into smaller pieces i.e. procedures. The only clean way to simplify your code is to pack your loops away inside sub-procedures, in order to simplify your high-level procedure.

For example, your high-level procedure would look like this:

```
Dim n As Long
n = 100
DoThing1 n
DoThing2 n
DoThing3 n
```

with lower-level procedures:

```
Sub DoThing1(ByVal n As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To n
        Statement1
    Next i
End Sub
```

and similar for the other two.